# Ошибка при подключении к MySQL БД через IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Файл properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/test?useSSL=false spring.datasource.username=name spring.datasource.password=pas spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Ошибка:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase (file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.12/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar) to field java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches.localDescs
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Полный отчёт:

```
    "C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\jbr\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=53481:C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\target\classes;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\lib\javax.persistence.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\lib\javax.transaction.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\lib\javax.jms.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\lib\javax.ejb.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\lib\javax.servlet.jsp.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\lib\javax.resource.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\lib\javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.2\aspectjweaver-1.9.2.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\3.2.0\HikariCP-3.2.0.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.3\javax.transaction-api-1.3.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.3.7.Final\hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.23.1-GA\javassist-3.23.1-GA.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.9.3\byte-buddy-1.9.3.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.5.Final\jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.4.0\classmate-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.1\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.4.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.1.2.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.1.2.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-aspects-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-mustache\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-mustache-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.1.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.11.1\log4j-api-2.11.1.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\snakeyaml-1.23.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\samskivert\jmustache\1.14\jmustache-1.14.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.7\jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.7\jackson-core-2.9.7.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.7\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.7.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.7\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.7.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.7\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.7.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.12\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.12\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.12.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.12\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.13.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.13.Final.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-devtools-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.13\mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar com.example.ApiConnect.Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.0.RELEASE)

2019-10-29 11:06:02.797  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.ApiConnect.Application       : Starting Application on msk-dev-017 with PID 3100 (C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis\target\classes started by vladislav.gilenko in C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IdeaProjects\apis)
2019-10-29 11:06:02.799  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.ApiConnect.Application       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-10-29 11:06:02.833  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-10-29 11:06:02.833  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-10-29 11:06:03.345  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-10-29 11:06:03.384  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 35ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2019-10-29 11:06:03.599  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cd8cde1a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-10-29 11:06:03.859  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-10-29 11:06:03.872  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-10-29 11:06:03.872  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
2019-10-29 11:06:03.878  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\jbr\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Users\vladislav.gilenko\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.]
2019-10-29 11:06:03.982  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-10-29 11:06:03.982  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1149 ms
2019-10-29 11:06:04.003  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-10-29 11:06:04.006  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-10-29 11:06:04.006  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-10-29 11:06:04.006  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'formContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-10-29 11:06:04.006  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-10-29 11:06:04.079  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-10-29 11:06:04.519  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-10-29 11:06:04.549  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-10-29 11:06:04.585  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
2019-10-29 11:06:04.586  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-10-29 11:06:04.660  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-10-29 11:06:04.750  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-10-29 11:06:05.205  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-10-29 11:06:05.231  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2019-10-29 11:06:05.245  WARN 3100 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'greetingController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'messageRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageRepo': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.persistence.SynchronizationType javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()'
2019-10-29 11:06:05.246  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-10-29 11:06:05.249  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-10-29 11:06:09.927  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2019-10-29 11:06:09.928  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase (file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.12/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar) to field java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches.localDescs
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2019-10-29 11:06:09.938  INFO 3100 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-29 11:06:09.946 ERROR 3100 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'greetingController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'messageRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageRepo': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.persistence.SynchronizationType javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.ApiConnect.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageRepo': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.persistence.SynchronizationType javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1239) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.persistence.SynchronizationType javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()'
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.<init>(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:665) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$buildPersistenceMetadata$1(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:447) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:543) ~[spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:432) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:406) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1044) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:550) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что я неправильно подключаюсь к удалённой базе mssql. Может кто-нибудь показать как правильно на примере db4free.net. Как правильно прописывать `spring.datasource.url=`

Comment: Хотя думаю, что правильно указываю:   `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/testingerapi?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=name
spring.datasource.password=pas
spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update`

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` говорит о том, что у вас нет определенного метода класса. Скорее всего это вызвано неправильным набором/отсутствием необходимой библиотеки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильным ответом является, что неправильно прописал подключение к базе данных.

То, что помогло:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.12.168/Test?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false
```